# In what sense is the Ricci Curvature Tensor an “average”?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I’ve heard that the Ricci tensor loosely represents an “average” curvature of some sort. The physical meaning of the Riemann tensor is relatively clear to me as I’ve seen how to derive it, but  the Ricci Tensor is a contraction of it that seems more mathematically abstract. I’ve also  seen that it has to do with how volumes are transported along geodesics, but I’m more interested in how accurate it is to call it an “average”.

Answer (score 6):

For any unit vector $v\in T_pM$, the Ricci curvature $\text{Ric}_p(v,v)$ is the average sectional curvature of all $2$-planes containing $v$.